# Can I target multiple live child selectors with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$( '#parent' ).on( 'click', '.a .b .c,.a .b .d,.a .b .e', function(){ ... });
```

the three selectors, to be clear are:

```
.a .b .c
.a .b .d
.a .b .e
```

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to reduce that somehow:

```
.a .b (.c,.d,.e)
```

And I know how to do it with non-live queries easily (e.g. with `.find`), but I specifically want this event to be attached to `$( '#parent' )`

Comment: simplest way would be give them a common class at server. Otherwise not enough detail given to provide other solutions

Comment: For the sake of my amusement, `.a .b :not(:not(.c, .d, .e))` works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit from OP in case anyone wants to use this: *read the warning in my comment below*

Is this what you looking for? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/feature-req-any-selector-filter

```
jQuery.expr[':'].any = function(el, i, match) {
    return jQuery.find.matches(match[3], [el]).length > 0;
};
```

Comment: Yes, and I actually implemented the same thing myself just now (with a different name).  Not sure if I like how it works internally to jQuery though :/

Comment: Okay, I'm accepting this because it's exactly what I asked for.  I like the name `is` or `matches` better (`matches` is the proposed name for this feature in CSS4).

Note, however, that there are huge performance implications for this solution.  If used as an actual selector, this is a very bad idea as it runs, in some cases, every node in the document through this function.  In the case of using it in an event, however, it's not a bad solution as it only runs every node in the tree above the element that the even ran against (still wasteful, but it only checks a few nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Answering this myself thanks to Felix:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].matches = function( elem, index, match ){
    return $( elem ).is( match[3] );
};

$( '#parent' ).on( 'click', '.a .b :matches( .c, .d, .e )', ... );
```

which should, for performance reasons, be optimized a bit to:

```
.a .b nodeTypeOrOtherSelector:matches( .c, .d, .e )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible but I would try getting creative with some regex:

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'c,d,e'.replace(/(\w+)/g, '.a.b.$1')
```

The idea is to create the selector before hand.

Comment: I like the idea, but not the look or having to teach other people I work with :)

Comment: @cwolves: I see what you mean. I also get the "having to teach people about regex" often. Wish more people knew how to use them, it makes code very compact and I do like the look, xD.

Comment: Well by "the look" in this case, I mean that it's supposed to be a fairly straight forward CSS selector, and this is kind of obfuscating it.  If I looked at it in a month, I'd have to either stare at it for a bit or paste it into a terminal

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the common `.a .b` ancestor selectors into the target context selector? This should work:

```
$('#parent .a .b').on('click', '.c, .d, .e', function(){ ... });
```

**Update:** @cwolves is correct in pointing out that this would only work for static `.a .b` i.e. present on the page at the time of attaching the handler, kind of defeating the purpose of delegated events in the first place.

Comment: because the `.a` and `.b` nodes change

Comment: @cwolves: what do you mean they change? if you're implying that elements you want to target may not be all siblings (different `.b`-qualifying nodes) or nephiews (different `.a`-qualifying nodes), they would still be all picked up by the context selector.

Comment: @cwolves: oh, never mind, I just saw the *I specifically want this event to be attached to $('#parent')* - curious why though?

Comment: When I say they change I mean new `.a` or `.b` nodes get added/removed.  `$( '#parent .a .b' )` will only pick up the nodes that are on the page when it runs

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over what the class names are, you can use a naming convention. Rahter than .c, .d, .e and so on, name them .c-d, .c-e, .c-f, etc. Then you can use `[class^="c-"]` as the selector.

Edit with more concreteness:

```
$( '#parent' ).on( 'click', '.a .b [class|="c"] ...
```

Comment: or, perhaps more simply `[class|="c"]` to better reflect the semantics.

Comment: This might be the best solution as it looks clean and can actually run against the CSS engine in most browsers (instead of running internally through Sizzle).  The solution I accepted, however, is more flexible (though performs way worse)

Answer (score -1):

One way to simplify the selector a little bit would be moving the `.a .b` test inside the callback:

```
$( '#parent' ).on('click', '.c, .d, .e', function(){
    if ($(this).closest('.a .b').length === 0) {
        // not the right element
        return;
    }
    // ...
});
```

But whether this is desirable from a performance or code maintenance point of view, I don't know.

Picking up on [elclanrs' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14764360/218196), you can create the selector dynamically:

```
var ancestors = '.a .b';
var selector = ancestors + ['.c', '.d', '.e'].join(', ' + ancestors);
```

---

Apart from that there is not much you can do. CSS selectors just don't work this way.

Comment: Your "CSS selectors just don't work that way" reminded me of something.  Answering this myself in a minutes by implementing `:matches` from the CSS4 spec

Comment: implemented, not sure I like the solution... jQuery runs every child node through the function :/

Comment: @Felix Kling: this would return a false positive for an element that matches `.a .b #parent .c/d/e` - however unlikely that is

Comment: @o.v.: True... could be fixed by adding `#parent`... but well.